# Unattended update: how to pass throught user settings to new installer?

Tags: install4j

I have to implement the following scenario:

1. Application is installed with user specific values like installation directory, server url, user home and more
2. User should start a stand-alone updater
3. updater should automatically check for update, download file and start the new installer in silent mode
4. After installation there should be a status message whether update was successful or not

Therefore I took the updater of the *Hello* sample app and removed the user input forms. Now the check is succesful and the file will be downloaded. But how to pass through the user input values to the new installer? Should I use the response file and set this one as an argument for the silent installation?

Thanks in adnvance
Hardie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new installer will read the existing response file from old installation if you add a "Load a response file" action to the "Installation location" screen. The default project template already has this action in place.

Comment: okay. But now there is one question left: how to handle values for custom components. I have implemented a drop-down list and set the value at the _checkComplete()_ method with _getContext().setVariable(...)_. For unattended mode I only have to check, if variable is already set (maybe by response.varfile) or not? Should I have to do this in _checkComplete()_ or _handleUnattended()_?

Comment: I have seen that the value of my custom component is not present at the default _response.varfile_ generated by install4j. How can I append the _response.varfile_ with this value?

Comment: Use `context.registerResponseFileVariable(...)` for that purpose.